# Exports not defined - Storybook + webpack 3 + babel 7 + commonjs

Tags: webpack, babeljs, storybook

I am working on a legacy code base. A few modules are in commonjs and a few are es6 modules. Recently, when I try to upgrade to babel 7, I receive the following error while trying to run the storybook:

> exports is not defined
>   ReferenceError: exports is not defined

The project uses storybook 3, webpack 3. Here is a snapshot of my babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function config(api) {
  api.cache(false);
  const presets = [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        modules: false,
      },
    ],
    '@babel/preset-flow',
    '@babel/preset-react'
  ];
  const plugins = [
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
  ];

  return {
    presets,
    plugins,
  };
};
```

Snapshot of webpack.config:

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    include: [
      path.resolve('src'),
    ],
    loader: 'babel-loader',
  },
```